# Resharper - modify string interpolation back to string.Format

Tags: c#, string, resharper, string-interpolation, string.format

some days ago i followed an advice of ReSharper to modify all string.Format's to string interpolations. I accepted the suggestion and changed it all throughout the complete solution.

Since we are working in a team, i discussed this change (afterwards, when the damage was done) and we decided to go back to the string.Format's to be sure nothing was broken.

Now, is there a way to tell ReSharper to change all my string interpolations back to string.Format's? I hope there is.

Notes:

- using Visual Studio 2015
- using ReSharper 2017.1.3
- Nothing broke after
  the change to interpolation, but it's just for esthetic reasons we
  decided to stay with our string.Format's

It would be great to have an easy way to do this instead of just undoing my checking to TFS (file per file, as there are other changing i want to keep).

Comment: You really find `string.Format` "nicer" than string interpolation?

Comment: Not me, but the rest of the team. I would leave it as it is, but well, apparantly once upon a time, someone in the team had something broken using interpolation so therefor the decission

Comment: i think sometimes it's nicer/better/more readable to use interpolation and sometimes it's better to use `string.Format`(f.e. localization or very long texts across multiple lines). It depends. So imo it's not a good dedision to only use one approach.

Comment: String interpolation is safer since String.Format can throw exceptions at runtime if the string format isn't compatible with the parameters passed in

Comment: @TimSchmelter one reason to go back to `String.Format` is when you generalize your code. In order to reduce duplications, you sometimes need to pass the format to the extracted method. Of course you *could*  keep string interpolation by passing a lambda / an Action instead and but that makes the code only harder to comprehend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the cursor on a interpolated string | hit Alt+Enter | Convert to 'string.format' | Convert to 'string.format' in solution

Comment: you are my hero of the day, thanks a lot, it worked!